# Como definir uma diretiva com Vue 2.0 que sempre faça o binding como string

Tags: vue.js

Estou começando agora com [Vue 2.0](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2) e estou criando diretivas para que eu possa manipular o estilo de um elemento com base no conteúdo dessa diretiva, assim:

```
Vue.directive('margin', function (el, binding) {
    $(el).css('margin', binding.value);
});
```

Meu problema é que, para que eu possa dar um binding no value, eu sou obrigado a deixar o campo sempre formatado como string, e isso eu vejo como desnecessário... assim:

```
<div class="foo" v-margin="'auto'"></div>
```

Se por acaso eu tiro as aspas simples de dentro do binding, ocorre a mensagem de erro:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "auto" is not defined on the instance but 
            referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties 
            in the data option.
```

Existe alguma forma para "forçar" a diretiva a sempre interpretar o meu binding como o texto simples? assim eu não precisaria passar a aspas simples do `'auto'`.

> **NOTA** Já tentei definir dentro da diretiva um `toString()` no parâmetro binding mas sem sucesso, assim:

```
Vue.directive('margin', function (el, binding) {
    $(el).css('margin', binding.value.toString()); // <- toString();
});
```

Comment: E se tentares `String(binding.value)`?

Comment: String(binding.value) tenta a conversão de uma variável para o tipo String que, nesse caso é a mesma coisa que o binding.value.toString().

Comment: É que como vi isto, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945202/whats-the-difference-between-stringvalue-vs-value-tostring pensei que pudesse resultar

Comment: É uma boa lógica de uso o String, só que o Vue interpreta um null.toString() como "" ;D

Comment: Eu até acho isso estranho, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vue.js/2368/custom-directives#t=201701091450173776812 e aqui https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html parece resultar sem problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que não seja possível, de acordo com ["Directives in Depth"](http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/directives.html):

> For security reasons, in inline expressions you can only access **properties and methods present on the current context** ViewModel and its parents.

Mas se quer que funcione e não veja problema em ver o warning, você pode utilizar `binding.expression` no lugar de `bindig.value`, o valor sempre será string, mas obviamente não é a melhor opção (até porque trocar uma aspas simples por um warning não parece ser uma boa troca).